# MS SQL Spatial Index and time for executing

Tags: sql-server, indexing, geography, spatial-index

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CollectionSite](
    [SiteCode] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [AddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
    //...
    [Location] [geography] NOT NULL,
```

table has approx 10000 records.

I have the following linq query:

```
        var list = dataContext.CollectionSites.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation)<3000000).OrderBy(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation))
            .ToList();
```

It's being executed approx 12-15 sec. Then I try to create a spatial index:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIX_CollectionSite_SiteCode ON CollectionSite([Location]) USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID
```

it's created successfully. But time for executing is the same.
Why index does not work?

version of EF Core is 2.2.4

**ADDED 01/01/2020**

It generates the following sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [p].[SiteCode], [p].[AddressId], [p].[Location]
FROM [CollectionSite] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Location].STDistance(@__myLocation_0) < 3000000.0E0
ORDER BY [p].[Location].STDistance(@__myLocation_0)',N'@__myLocation_0 varbinary(22)',@__myLocation_0=0xE6100000010C0403081F4ACA4040ACADD85F76FB5BC0
```

and it's being executed 12-15 sec from .NET app, but less than 1 sec directly

Next Step. I added time marker to the following place:

```
        var query = dataContext.CollectionSites
            .Where(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation) < 3000000)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation))
            .Select(p => new { p.SiteCode, p.AddressId, p.Location })
            ;

        var ms11 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        var list = query.ToList();
```

and this ms11 has these 12-15 sec, `ToList()` is being executed less than 1 sec!
Why query is being combined so long?

Comment: I could be way off but if you create the index on location but select based on IsActive and OpenToPublic I don't think you're buying yourself anything. Location is the predicate used to populate list but that is not being executed on the database, it's happening after the dataset in query is returned which is being selected by IsActive and OpenToPublic.

Comment: @BillRuhl the first statement doesn't _execute_ the query.  The second statement should generate and execute a query with all three predicates.

Comment: Please include the version of EF or LINQ2SQL you are using, and the actual query and query plan generated.  And try some simple TSQL queries to observer the index behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I stand corrected. I was under the impression that that EF would load "var = query" first then apply the additional predicate to populate "var = list"...

Comment: @BillRuhl the IQueryable won't be executed until you run .AsEnumerable(), .ToList(), .First(), .Single(), etc.  Basically any extension method that doesn't return an IQueryable will execute the query.

Comment: @BillRuhl, modified query request and the same problem

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , I added version of EF, I can't show SQL, because I can't execute profiler on my SQL server (I don't have rights)

Comment: EF Core 2.2, right?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft right!

Comment: Something in app startup.  Perhaps Migrations or DbContext initialization.  Use the Visual Studio code profiler to figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is going on.  Try this simple repro.  It searches 10000 geography results *without* a spatial index in under 1sec.  With a spatial index it's even faster.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Samples.EFLogging;
using NetTopologySuite;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfTest
{
    public class CollectionSite
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SiteCode { get; set; }

        public int AddressId { get; set; }

        public Geometry Location { get; set; }
    }
    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public Db() : this("Server=.;Database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true")
        {
        }
        public Db(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;

        }

        public DbSet<CollectionSite> CollectionSites { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.UseRelationalNulls().UseNetTopologySuite());

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        }
    }



public class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var gf = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var loc = new CollectionSite()
                    {
                        Location = gf.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(-90 + i / 1000.0, 45 + i / 1000.0)),
                        AddressId = i,
                        SiteCode = "site" + i
                    };

                    db.CollectionSites.Add(loc);

                }
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.ConfigureLogging( s => Console.WriteLine(s));
                var myLocation = gf.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(-90, 45));

                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();

                var list = db.CollectionSites
                             .Where(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation) < 30000)
                             .OrderBy(p => p.Location.Distance(myLocation))
                             .ToList();

                Console.WriteLine($"Found {list.Count} sites in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

outputs

```
Found 221 sites in 982ms
Hit any key to exit
```

And the query it generates is:

```
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[AddressId], [c].[Location], [c].[SiteCode]
FROM [CollectionSites] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[Location].STDistance(@__myLocation_0) < 3000.0E0
ORDER BY [c].[Location].STDistance(@__myLocation_0)
```

Comment: I have SiteCode as key, not id field. I see only this difference...

Comment: How does a TSQL query like above perform for you?

Comment: really, SQL is being executed during some seconds, but from .NET application it's being executed during 12-15 sec...